# Find a modulus of continuity $\delta_{\epsilon,x,y}$ for the continuous function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a modulus of continuity $\delta_{\epsilon,x,y}$ for the continuous function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}$.

Side issue: since the question uses $\delta_{\epsilon,x,y}$, does that mean $\delta$ may depend on $x,y$?  So we are basically finding a modulus for an arbitrary point?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Is this asking for such a function for uniform continuity or just continuity at every point?  Also what variables can this function have in these two cases?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I posted it exactly as it appeared in Courant's intro analysis book Vol 2, its an old book so not sure if has the same meaning as current definition of modulus of continuity which according to your wiki link suggests that its only relevant to uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen 
In this problem I think it means to find the modulus for a particular point $x_0,y_0$ rather than over interval or $\mathbb{R}$ as uniform continuity should only depend on $\epsilon$ and it would have only used the notation $\delta_\epsilon$.  But I suppose if you find modulus for uniform continuity, then that would be even stronger.

Comment: I've posted some calculations and thoughts I had earlier when I looked at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: Depending on what the OP means by "Modulus of Continuity at a point $(x_0, y_0)$" this might not totally answer the question*

---

We seek a function $\omega$, which we call the "modulus of continuity of $f$", satisfying $d_1(f(z_1) - f(z_2)) \le \omega( d_2(z_1,z_2) )$ for all $z_1, z_2$ in our domain. We don't actually get one here, since our function $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Nevertheless, we will derive something similar which will hopefully answer the query at hand.

We will do this over the course of a few steps. First note that given any $z_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and given the $f$ in your post,

\begin{align} d_1(f(z_1), f(z_2)) &= |f(z_1),f(z_2)|\\ &= |\sqrt{1+e^{x_1 y_1}}-\sqrt{1+e^{x_2 y_2}}|\\ &= \left|\frac{e^{x_1 y_1}-e^{x_2 y_2}}{\sqrt{1+e^{x_1 y_1}}+\sqrt{1+e^{x_2 y_2}}}\right|\\ &\le |e^{x_1 y_1}-e^{x_2 y_2}| \end{align}

The problem now comes down to expressing this in terms of $d_2(z_1, z_2).$ We will use a few standard analysis tricks. First, let's consider the easier case $|e^x - e^y|$ for $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}.$ Note that the mean value theorem tells us that there is some $c \in (x,y)$ such that $|e^x - e^y|\le e^c|x-y| \le e^{\max(x,y)}|x-y|.$ If we let $x = x_1y_1$ and $y = x_2 y_2$ and do this argument we find
$$|e^{x_1 y_1}-e^{x_2 y_2}| \le e^{\max(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)}|x_1y_1-x_2y_2| $$
We now need to simplify the quantity $|x_1y_1-x_2y_2|.$ To do this, note
\begin{align}|x_1y_1-x_2y_2| &= \left|x_1y_1-x_2y_1+x_2y_1-x_2y_2\right|\\
&\le \left|x_1y_1-x_2y_1\right|+\left|x_2y_1-x_2y_2\right|\\
&= \left|y_1\right|\left|x_1-x_2\right|+\left|x_2\right|\left|y_1-y_2\right|\\
&= \max(|y_1|,|x_1|)(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)\end{align}
Finally, we recall that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1 \le \sqrt{2}\lVert \cdot \rVert_2 $ on $\mathbb{R}^2,$ so that
$|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2| \le \sqrt{2}d_2(z_1,z_2).$

Putting all of this together, we get the following:
\begin{align} d_1(f(z_1), f(z_2)) & \le |e^{x_1 y_1}-e^{x_2 y_2}|\\
& \le e^{\max(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)}|x_1y_1-x_2y_2|\\
& \le e^{\max(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)}\max(|y_1|,|x_1|)(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)\\
& \le \underbrace{\sqrt{2}e^{\max(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)}\max(|y_1|,|x_1|)d_2(z_1, z_2)}_{\omega?}\\
& \stackrel{?}{=} \omega(d_2(z_1, z_2))
\end{align}
This is of course not quite the way we want $\omega$ to work for a true modulus of continuity, but I'm not quite sure what your textbook is looking for where you say "modulus of continuity at a point"

Comment: Not really sure what you are doing, since you claim the function is not uniformly continuous (why is this?) but then proceed to find a modulus for uniform continuity (which should be more difficult).

Comment: @helios321 I don't derive a true modulus of continuity, which is why there are question marks at the end of the proof. As I mention at the top, one cannot find a true modulus of continuity, since our function isn't uniformly continuous. It is uniformly continuous on compact sets I should note. Because your function isn't uniformly continuous and I don't know what your book means by "modulus of continuity at a point" (if your book defines your delta notation, you need to provide that) I outlined some calculations which show why exactly we can't get a modulus of continuity on all of...

Comment: @helios321... $\mathbb{R} $ (due to the max function between points). Note this goes away on compact sets by boundedness! So what I provide really is a modulus of continuity, but only on the compact sets where such a concept is defined.